# Wake lock for Mac OS X

Tags: android, macos, wakelock

In Android, there's wake lock to keep the screen on. So, is there Mac equivalent to keep the screen on for a PC running Mac OS X? If that is the case, what are the APIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in OS X it is done at the OS level through `IOPMLib`, the Power Management subsystem, which is also the subsystem that controls `AppNap` under OS X Mavericks.

Here's an example of what we do when performing heavy calculations.  In our case, we keep the CPU from sleeping, but you can prevent the display from sleeping by using `kIOPMAssertionTypePreventUserIdleDisplaySleep` where we used `kIOPMAssertionTypePreventUserIdleSystemSleep`.

```
@property IOPMAssertionID currentPowerAssertion;


- (void)assertPowerRequirement:(NSString*)reason
{
    // don't re-assert if we're already here
    if (_currentPowerAssertion)
        return;

    IOPMAssertionID assertionID;

    IOReturn success = IOPMAssertionCreateWithName( 
            kIOPMAssertionTypePreventUserIdleSystemSleep,   // prevent CPU from going to sleep 
            kIOPMAssertionLevelOn,                          // we are turning this on
            (__bridge CFStringRef)reason,                   // here's why
            &assertionID);                                  // reference for de-asserting

    if (success == kIOReturnSuccess) {
        _currentPowerAssertion = assertionID;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Power assert failed");
    }
}

- (void)deassertPowerRequirement
{
    if (!_currentPowerAssertion)
        return;

    IOReturn success = IOPMAssertionRelease(_currentPowerAssertion);
    if (success !=kIOReturnSuccess) {
        NSLog(@"Power de-assert failed");
    }

    _currentPowerAssertion = 0;
}
```

In this case, this is in our App delegate, and we have the `currentPowerAssertion` property to keep track.   Since we only use one assertion state and only for one purpose, we use a single storage mechanism.   However, you can assert multiple times from different parts of your program, as long as you balance the assertions with de-assertions and use appropriate `reason`.   Specifications from Apple mandate a reason be given (not NULL), and suggest that the Application name and task be described in the assertion.

It's important to make sure that you de-assert when you don't need this any longer, although assertions are kept on a per-app basis, so when your App quits, they will automatically be de-asserted.

Answer (score 3):

To add to it, there are also command-line tools, like the built-in `caffeinate`.